# Read wav file from computer to arduino mega

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, byte

I have to read wav file(I decided to do it with python) and write bytes from file to serial port. Here's my python code(with a little changes to fix bytes transmitting/receiving)

```
import serial, time
ser = serial.Serial(6, 19200, timeout=0,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)
f = open("out.wav", "rb")
try:
    n=0
    while n!=7000:
        f.read(1)
        n+=1
    while n != 7002:
        byte = f.read(1)
        ser.write(byte)
        n+=1
    finally:
        print(byte)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(ser.read())
        f.close()
        ser.close()
```

and here's my arduino code to figure out what I'm receiving

```
byte buf;
void setup(){
Serial.begin(19200);
}
void loop(){
if(Serial.available()>0){
    buf=Serial.read();
    Serial.flush();
    Serial.println(buf);
    }
}
```

And my main problem that i'm getting different bytes from python and arduino. I've tried a lot of things but finally I'm here because I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Serial port communication offers the option to transmit a parity bit along with each byte. This can be used to detect transmission errors.

On the Arduino, you use Serial.begin(19200). This configures to use no parity bit, implicitly.

On the machine running Python, you use serial.Serial(6, 19200, timeout=0,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1). This sets an even parity bit, explicitly.

Hence, Python sends an even parity bit for each byte and the arduino expects to receive no parity bits at all. This may be the cause for your observation of receiving different bytes than expected.

Try this on the machine running Python:

```
serial.Serial(6, 19200, timeout=0)
```

This should implicitly configure to use no parity bits, just as you did with the Arduino.